# Adding a Merged Dictionary to a Merged Dictionary

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary

I can't seem to be able to add a merged dictionary to a collection of merged dictionaries within XAML.

**Theme.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Palette.Blue.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Template.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**Application Resources**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/> 
            <!--
            <ResourceDictionary Source=="/Mine;component/Themes/Palette.Blue.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Template.xaml"/>
            -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Note: if I put both ResourceDictionaries in the Appication.Resources MergedDictionary (comment out the theme.xaml and uncomment the other two dictionaries) they both load correctly. However, the way our resources are defined, this may mean that quite a few resources will be loaded, and for dynamic loading I'd like to be able to define templates.

Comment: is that the full code of the theme.xaml?  because i think you only need to start and end it with ResourceDictionary tag to make it work

Comment: No, it's actually in a merged dictionary already. It just doesn't seem to inherit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an optimization bug, see [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120117125916/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553528/defaultstylekey-style-not-found-in-inner-mergeddictionaries)

> On the creation of every object in
> XAML, if a default style is present
> (i.e. style w/ a key of Type) that
> style should be applied. As you can
> imagine there are several performance
> optimizations to make that (implied)
> lookup a light weight as possible. One
> of them is that we don’t look inside
> Resource Dictionaries unless they are
> flagged as “containing default
> Styles”. There is a bug: if all your
> default styles are nested in merged
> dictionaries three levels deep (or
> deeper) the top dictionary does not
> get flagged so the search skips it.
> The work around is to put a default
> Style to something, anything,  in the root
> Dictionary.

So adding a dummy style to the root dictionary fixes this. Example

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Mine;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Dummy Style, anything you won't use goes -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I've run into this exact problem in .NET 4 and this solves it.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me. Upon starting, it throws an exception (DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is not valid for 'Foreground') which indicates that the resource dictionaries are not getting added. Mine is set up identically to the code above on .NET 4.5.

Comment: this doesn't not work in VS2010 .net 4.0 this does NOT compile. error `Error 7 Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content.`

Comment: Would anyone know if this bug is fixed in .NET 4.5 or later?  Microsoft Connect has been retired so I can't tell from the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code has a double equal sign in the App.xaml merged resource dictionary source for Palette.Blue.xaml.  I'm assuming this is a typo for your example posted here, and not your real problem though.

It can be tricky to figure out how to link all the resources directly in XAML. The easiest way to do it is from the Resources panel in Blend. I created a Silverlight app with resource files named like your example, then opened the project in Blend and very quickly linked them together.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme.xaml" />
                <!--
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Palette.Blue.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Template.xaml"/>
                -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Theme.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Palette.Blue.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Template.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Template.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Palette.Blue.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueSolidColorBrush" Color="SkyBlue" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Honeydew">
        <TextBox Text="Read Only Textbox"
                 Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBoxStyle}" />
        <TextBox Text="Blue Textbox"
                 Background="{StaticResource BlueSolidColorBrush}" />
        <TextBox Text="Read Only, Blue Textbox"
                 Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBoxStyle}"
                 Background="{StaticResource BlueSolidColorBrush}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Of course, if you're linking resources from different assemblies it will look different. Actually, in that case, I'd suggest looking into merging your dictionaries in the code behind.

Comment: That was apparently a transcription error (not in the actual file.) I know how to add each resource individually (via code behind or creating a new MergedDictionary) but the issue seems to be something to do with adding a mergedDictionary to a ResourceDictionary either as the source or part of a seperate merged dictionary.

Comment: Check the build action of your dictionary xaml files. You might need to change it from the default Page to Resource.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on one of your own controls I've found that another solution is setting the `DefaultStyleKey` property to null:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

I have no idea why this works, but it seems to!

Comment: This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569389/1450491) explains how OverrideMetadata works