# GridSplitter acts differently when moved to external resource (UserControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gridsplitter

Since my WPF application uses `GridSplitter`s on several occasions, I want to extract that XAML snippet into a separate `UserControl`.

Of course, using a `ResourceDictionary` would be nicer. But that way, I can only define a `ControlTemplate` for the splitter's content and use it within the `Template`-attribute afterwards - which removes the ability to define all those `GridSplitter` attributes only once and then consecutively use them.

**The `GridSplitter` `UserControl`, GridSplitter.xaml:**

```xml
<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <GridSplitter.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
      <Grid>
        <Button Content="⁞" />
        <Rectangle Fill="#00FFFFFF" />
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </GridSplitter.Template>
</GridSplitter>
```

**The usage in MainWindow.xaml:**

```xml
<Window
         (...)
         xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Yoda.Frontend.Resources"
         (...)>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="200" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- (...) -->
    <uc:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />
    <!-- (...) -->
  </Grid>
    <!-- (...) -->
</Window>
```

The result of using the above code is a splitter which can't be moved in any direction.

However, using the `ResourceDictionary` dictionary approach mentioned above, I get a movable `GridSplitter`.
But despite working perfectly directly in **MainWindow.xaml**, it only resizes the third grid column.

Sure, setting `Width` isn't recommended when using `GridSplitter`. But why does it work whenever the splitter is defined within the main window and only fails to do so when used as an `UserControl`? And how to fix that in an MVVM, no code-behind way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you only what to have a nice looking splitter, you can use this code:

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" />
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20" Width="Auto" />
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!-- (...) -->
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
<TextBlock Text="⁞" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           IsHitTestVisible="False" />
<!-- (...) -->
```

Another solution would be to define the `ControlTemplate` as a resource and then use that for the `GridSplitter`:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}" x:Key="gridSplitter">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Button Content="⁞" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <Rectangle Fill="#00FFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- (...) -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource gridSplitter}" />
        <!-- (...) -->
    </Grid>
    <!-- (...) -->
</Grid>
```

There's also a solution if you really want to use the set properties within the splitter template: use a style to add those. It would look like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}" x:Key="gridSplitter">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Button Content="⁞" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#00FFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}" x:Key="styleGridSplitter">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource gridSplitter}" />
        <Setter Property="ResizeBehavior" Value="PreviousAndNext" />
        <Setter Property="ResizeDirection" Value="Columns" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- (...) -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource styleGridSplitter}"/>
        <!-- (...) -->
    </Grid>
    <!-- (...) -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: First of all: thanks _a lot_ for this _awesome_ and diverse answer. I mixed up that `ControlTemplate`s need to be defined within a `Style`, not the other way round. From there, I was even able to improve your answer. :) So, I'm happily accepting your answer as soon as you can clarify one remaining issue: why do I have to switch from `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource` in order to avoid runtime exceptions? **Note:** I defined the `GridSplitter` in a separate XAML file for inclusion within App.xaml's `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` (next to one for the `ContextMenu` that's unrelated).

Comment: The solutions I have suggested, does not use a different control, but the default one that is present in WPF. Does your solution now still use a control made by you?

Comment: No, I simply switched to your 3rd solution (with the addition that I mentioned in my first comment regarding a separate file and including that file within App.xaml's `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`). BTW: Thanks for hinting me at `IsHitTestVisible`! :)

Comment: StaticResource are not reactive to Merge of dictionaries. The Merge is done at runtime, at some time. DynamicResource is reactive to Merge. I think that this is the cause.

Comment: Awesome answer! FWIW, it's explained in a bit more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325015/wpf-problem-with-static-resource-shared-in-merged-dictionaries/4326738#4326738). And as promised before, your perfect answer is marked accepted now. Thanks a lot! :)