# Style: BasedOn and DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, custom-controls

When I create a custom control in Visual Studio a static constructor is added automatically:

```
static MyListBoxItem()
 {
     DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyListBoxItem)));
 }
```

The Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:MyListBoxItem}">
  <Style.Resources>
     <!--SelectedItem with focus-->
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
 </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

then gives an empty layout. Without the code in the static constructor the layout is correct. As long as you do not set `OverridesDefaultStyle` to true.

When I add  `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"` to the Style the layout is correct with and without the static constructor code. `OverridesDefaultStyle` has no effect anymore.

I would prefer that the style of a custom control defaults to the style of the base type.
It looks to me as if the code in the static constructor can be omitted.
But why then is it generated by default?

Comment: If you look again at the parameters in your `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata` method, you'll see that there is no mention of `ListBoxItem`... all that code is saying is that the `Style` that you provide there should be the default `Style` for an object of type `MyListBoxItem`.

Comment: The `DefaultStyleKey` code sets a StyleKey as I understand it, not a Style? Therefore I was wondering why the Style with that implicit type-key was not applied.

Comment: You are correct that the `StyleKey` is not actually a `Style`, but it relates to the `Style`, or *is a reference* to the `Style` as I understand it. That line of code is still used to tell the `Framework` to look at your `Style` in `generic.xaml` for the default `Style` for your control. I'm not sure why it is not working. This is an interesting question, but unfortunately I am currently unable to test your scenario... I will try to when I get home later.

Comment: Just to be safe: I do not use `generic.xaml` - moved it to another file.

Comment: Maybe *that* is why your `Style` is not applied... try moving it back to the `generic.xaml` file. That is the file that the Framework will look in for the default `Style` for `CustomControl`s.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey.aspx) Page:

> A control typically overrides the default value of this property to be its own type, but in some cases could also use a base type for which a style in the theme dictionaries exists. This is only practical if the control templates of the base control entirely define the visual representation of that derived control, and if whatever additional members the derived types expose do not require additional elements as part of the control template.

In your case you want your custom control to use the base control style by default. To achieve that either you have to remove that line from static constructor or replace it with the following line to indicate you want to use the base control style.

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ListBoxItem)));
```

I guess, removing that line from static constructor would be better.

Comment: This is a possibility. No OverrideMetadata and no BasedOn in the default style also works.