# datatemplate in app.xaml is not getting picked up without any styles?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, styles, app.xaml

I have a DataTemplate in app.xaml that binds a view to a viewmodel.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:someviewmodeltype}">
        <vw:somevwcontrol />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

the above template doesn't get applied if there are no styles. The moment I put a style, something like ...

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:someviewmodeltype}">
        <vw:somevwcontrol />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

datatemplate gets picked up and produces the desired results ... I am not sure whats happening there ... could anybody clarify this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229395/trouble-referencing-a-resource-dictionary-that-contains-a-merged-dictionary/4166345#4166345). The question is not exactly the same, that one contained merged dictionaries being skipped but it's most likely the same bug.

This is an optimization bug, see [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553528/defaultstylekey-style-not-found-in-inner-mergeddictionaries).

> On the creation of every object in
>   XAML, if a default style is present
>   (i.e. style w/ a key of Type) that
>   style should be applied. As you can
>   imagine there are several performance
>   optimizations to make that (implied)
>   lookup a light weight as possible. One
>   of them is that we don’t look inside
>   Resource Dictionaries unless they are
>   flagged as “containing default
>   Styles”. There is a bug: if all your
>   default styles are nested in merged
>   dictionaries three levels deep (or
>   deeper) the top dictionary does not
>   get flagged so the search skips it.
>   The work around is to put a default
>   Style to something, anything, in the
>   root Dictionary.

I see you've already found the workaround as well, just add a default dummy style in App.xaml. It doesn't have to have any setters etc, something like this will do as well

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:someviewmodeltype}">
        <vw:somevwcontrol />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" /> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Spent a whole day looking for this. Solved!

Comment: This happened to me 4 years later in VS 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Another pitfall is leaving out the `{x:Type}` from the `DataType` attribute.

### WRONG

This builds, runs and fails silently:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="local:MyType">
```

### RIGHT

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
```