# Context Menu Click show Popup

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a ***POP up*** on a context menu button click in C#.Please help.

And thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** .

Comment: Take a look to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845689/opening-new-window-in-mvvm-wpf

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get better answers, please note that this site will not do your work. Please show some effort - what have you tried? Have you done research?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Window class. You can design that then any way you want. You can create and show a window modally like this:

```
MyWindow popup = new MyWindow();
popup.ShowDialog();
```

You can add a custom property for your result value, or if you only have two possible results ( + possibly undeterminate, which would be `null`), you can set the window's [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) property before closing it and then check for it (it is the value returned by `ShowDialog()`).