# Opening new window in a MVVM WPF Class Libary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Basically I am looking for [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846192/7696590), but for **Class Libraries**.

I am currently maintaining a larger WPF Solution where each part is loaded as a **Add-In**.
I'd like to create a service for all of these **Add-Ins** to implement which opens a `Window` without using UI elements in the **ViewModel**, basically looking like this:

```
class WindowService:IWindowService
{
    public void ShowWindow(object viewModel)
    {
        var win = new Window();
        win.Content = viewModel;
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

To simplify it, let's say we have 4 Projects:

**1. Client**

- Client.exe - MainWindow and App.xaml is in here
- Services.dll  - Services like WindowService and Reflection are in here
- Interfaces.dll - Contains Interfaces for above assemblies

---

**2. Add-Ins**

- AddIn.dll - WPF Class Library, Contains WPF View/ViewModel, References to Interfaces

The Answer I linked defines `DataTemplates` in the `App.Xaml`, but I can't define `DataTemplates` for Classes I don't know at that point, since Add-Ins are loaded using **Reflection** at Runtime.

**Where would I put my `DataTemplates` in order to get the linked Answer to work for Class Libraries without an `App.Xaml`?**

Comment: Where is ViewModel/View? in the main assembly or add-ins assemblies? Do the full name of type is fixed or dynamic? Maybe you can add some code to help to understand?

Comment: I edited my Question for better understanding. Hope it resolves your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is have a xaml resource file in each of my class libraries, and programatically merge these into the main application resources.

Say the class library project assembly name is "MyProject.Client" and it contains the resource file \Views\Resources\LibraryStyles.xaml. The code to merge this would look like:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
    new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProject.Client;component/Views/Resources/LibraryStyles.xaml",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
```