# Is there a way for a WPF page to keep its style when in a Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I have a WPF page that I've styled like this:

[image: WPF Page Example]

When I set the source to the WPF page, it looks like it loads. However, the hatched background style disappears.

[image: WPF Page In Frame Example]

The button is just a test on the main Window. The background remains from the Window and the Page background isn't inherited.

Any ideas?

Frame:

```
<Frame Source="{Binding ProductFrameSource}" Name="frameProducts" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

private Uri _ProductFrameSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/<omitted>.<omitted>.UI;component/Views/Products/<omitted>/Products_<omitted>.xaml");
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a property indicating the current product page to display
        /// </summary>
        public Uri ProductFrameSource
        {
            get { return _ProductFrameSource; }
            set
            { 
                _ProductFrameSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ProductFrameSource");
            }
        }
```

Page Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0 0 40 40" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0 0 100 100" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF1C1C1C" Geometry="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M  -10 77.5 L 22.5  110
                                               M  -10 52.5 L 47.5  110
                                               M  -10 27.5 L 72.5  110
                                               M  -10  2.5 L 97.5  110
                                               M  2.5  -10 L  110 97.5
                                               M 27.5  -10 L  110 72.5
                                               M 52.5  -10 L  110 47.5 
                                               M 77.5  -10 L  110 22.5">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="#FF908B91" Thickness=".5" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: @HighCore I'm not sure how helpful it will be, but I've edited my post to include the relevant code.

Comment: @HighCore One thing I did saw that I messed up on, was the RaisePropertyChanged method. I was calling the wrong property. But I changed it to the correct one. It didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you were not doing some weird winforms-like overriding OnRender() and painting the thing manually in code. haha =)

Comment: Oh. Right. Thankfully, I've dropped most of my bad WinForms habits ;)

Answer (score 1):

Where are you defining the `Page` Style? Is it in `App.xaml` or in one of the parents of the `Page`?.

Please take a look here:

- [page.DataContext not inherited from parent Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame)

Reading that it implies the style will only be inherited if it's put in App.xaml due to the `Isolated` hosting behaviour.

As to why it works when you start up but not after you change the frame source....this is just a guess but it could be just a bug, or the Isolation isn't active at that point for some reason.

If putting the Style in App.xaml doesn't work or isn't practical then you could put the `Style` inside a `ResourceDictionary` defined in a separate .XAML file, and then in your `Page` create a `ResourceDictionary` that merges in that .XAML containing your shared style (or do a similar thing in code-behind to place your style into the .Resources dictionary of the Page).

FrameProductsPageStyle.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0 0 40 40" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0 0 100 100" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF1C1C1C" Geometry="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M  -10 77.5 L 22.5  110
                                               M  -10 52.5 L 47.5  110
                                               M  -10 27.5 L 72.5  110
                                               M  -10  2.5 L 97.5  110
                                               M  2.5  -10 L  110 97.5
                                               M 27.5  -10 L  110 72.5
                                               M 52.5  -10 L  110 47.5 
                                               M 77.5  -10 L  110 22.5">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="#FF908B91" Thickness=".5" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your Page's XAML:

```
<Page>
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary 
            Source="FrameProductsPageStyle.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
</Page>
```

Use a suitable "pack" URL to reference your XAML resource dictionary depending on whether it is a loose file or part of a component/assembly.

Some links:

- [Add ResourceDictionary to class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173622/add-resourcedictionary-to-class-library)

Comment: Yeah. It's in App.xaml. You can see [here](http://i3.minus.com/ibzAF0Sn8wKmfY.PNG). I basically have two XAML files in my "Skins" folder. All of the styles for every control is in those files. They're exactly the same, except for color changes.

Comment: You could be running into the optimization bug....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057213/why-does-styles-dont-work-at-runtime-in-wpf-when-using-multiple-mergeddictiona

Comment: Maybe. I added the dummy style line, but it still didn't work. Is there something else beyond just adding the line that I have to do? I looked at those threads, but it sounded as if I should just add that line and it would work. But those guys are creating a resource dictionary in a separate file with the themes. Then referencing the themes in the app.xaml. I'm just adding the theme directly to the app.xaml. [http://i5.minus.com/iQ1xn32Fp8nBU.png](http://i5.minus.com/iQ1xn32Fp8nBU.png)

Comment: As an experiment only, could you refer to your Skin from a ResourceDictionary in your Page itself...just curious if that works or  not before exploring other things.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back with you. I was focusing on some other things. I removed the resource dictionary from app.xaml and applied it to the page resource dictionary. The behavior is the same. http://i5.minus.com/ib1zxCkt9aa2Vk.png