# Dynamically load ResourceDictionary - not working on application startup

Tags: c#, wpf, skin

I need to implement Skinning in a WPF application. User have the option to select a particular skin and I'm saving that skin as local(as an XML). On the application startup(`App` class constructor), I'm reading that user selected skin from xml and adding corresponding resource dictionary using `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add()` method. On the initial window load the skinning is not working and after the startup window load if we try to change the theme, it works as expected. So I moved the code block from App.xaml constructor to Startup window constructor, and it works fine.

I just override the `OnLoadCompleted` and `OnStartup` event and moved the code that I written in constructor to events, but no use.

So is there any way to do it from `App.xaml`?

Comment: When you override `OnStartup`, have you put your code before or after `base.OnStartup(e);`?

Comment: Perhaps you suffer from an issue (hard to tell since i don't know what exactly you are doing) where a workaround might be possible. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4166345/2819245)

Comment: @XAMeLi - before base.OnStartup(e).

Comment: @XAMeLi - tried both. same result.. :(