# Cannot Locate Resource After Changing the Command Line Arguments in VS2012

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, xamlparseexception

I have a working C# program which requires a set of command line arguments to start. My problem is that when I change the arguments in the project settings of Visual Studio 2012 (VS) and run the application, a `XamlParseException` is thrown shortly after startup:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.'
---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'theme/textblockstyle.xaml'.
...
at MyAssembly.View.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()
at MyAssembly.View.MainWindow..ctor()
```

The "missing" resource is referenced in `MainWindow.xaml` and has nothing to do with the given command line arguments:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAssembly;component/Theme/TextBlockStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

The interesting thing is that after rebuilding the project, the exception does not pop up anymore. Of course, I would like to have a less cumbersome solution than this, so I tried the following ideas:

- Change the "Build Action" of `TextBlockStyle.xaml` from "Page" to "Resource"
- Circumvent an optimization bug of VS by adding a dummy style to the root dictionary like in question ["Trouble referencing a Resource Dictionary that contains a Merged Dictionary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229395/trouble-referencing-a-resource-dictionary-that-contains-a-merged-dictionary).

None of it resolved the problem however. What can I do in order to avoid a rebuild each time I change the command line arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two steps resolved the problem for me:

- Change the fallback language in the assembly settings from

  `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]`

  to

  `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("")]`
- Remove the UI culture of the project:

  `<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>`

Maybe someone can elaborate on that. I don't understand why changing the command line parameters had an influence on finding language resources.