# WPF window style not being applied

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a ResourceDictionary that contains Style definitions for controls used within my application.

All of the styles are applied properly to the controls in the window...but the style in the ResourceDictionary for the window itself is not being applied.

This is the XAML in my ResourceDictionary that contains the style that I want to apply to my window:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:primatives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF121212"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="768"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="1024"></Setter>
    </Style>
<!-- .... -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the XAML for the window that I am working with (trying to get this style to apply):

```
<Window x:Class="TryingStyles"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TryingStyles">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StylesDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>    
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,14,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TabControl Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,43,0,0" Name="TabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
                <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Name="TabItem1">
                    <Grid></Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <GroupBox Header="GroupBox1" Margin="268,43,12,12" Width="396"></GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It appears that the style for the window is applied when I view the window in the IDE's "Design view" but when I run the application the style is not applied.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It appears that there is no proper solution to your problem. TargetType in Styles doesn't manage derived types.
Here are two alternatives :
You can put a key in your style and apply the style to all your Windows.

```
    <!-- Resource file -->    
    <ResourceDictionary ...>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="WindowDefaultStyle">
            <!-- .... -->    
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <!-- Window file -->
    <Window Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=WindowDefaultStyle}">
```

Or you can use the BasedOn property of the Style.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF121212"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="768"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="1024"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Inherit from the BaseStyle and define for the MainWindow class -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MainWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: You should also check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml

Answer (score 4):

It's very strange that it works with the designer but not when the application runs.
The problem seems to be the TargetType of your Style. Wpf seems not be able to match the Window class with your derivated class TryingStyles.

Change your TargetType and it will work :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:primatives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:TryingStyles}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF121212"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="768"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="1024"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- .... -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: While this works, I will have to do this for every window in my application. I would rather have one window style that can apply to all of the windows in my app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite late to the party here, but I found a solution to have `Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"` apply to every window application-wide, as one would expect. For the record, the reason this doesn't work is because each window you create is not a Window but a new type that derives from window (e.g. "MainWindow"), and Style's TargetType doesn't apply to derived classes. Anyway:

First, ensure your App.xaml has a Startup property defined; so inside the `<Application>` tag you'd add `Startup="Application_Startup"` or whatever you want to call the startup method.

Then, inside App.xaml.cs add:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(Window))
    });
}
```

where the method name matches whatever you listed as the Startup property in App.xaml. And of course, if you already have an existing startup method being run, just add the code contained within to that.

This basically just fixes it so that keyless Styles targeting "Window" will apply their changes to every window in your application, as you probably expected would occur without this code snippet. (That is of course assuming your style is already scoped application-wide, for example by containing it within a ResourceDictionary that is merged into App.xaml.)