# Why the WPF Window always get Default Style?

Tags: wpf, styles, window

I have tried to set the `Style` for WPF `Window` in XAML. I am  able to see my changes in VS Designer, but when I run the application it will always get the default `Style`.

Not Working:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

If I give that `Style` with Key and applying that `Style` to `Window` then it is working.

Working:

```
<Style x:Key="window" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

There is any reason need to give `Style` with key for `Window`?

Can any one please explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to add construction in `Window`:

```
Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"
```

Style is in the file `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WindowStyleHelp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- In this case, the key is optional --> 
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Window}" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Window in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowStyleHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: and how it is different from what OP posted in his question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Target types in style doesn't get applied on derived types.

Either you use `StaticResource` to apply key on all your windows -

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
```

OR

Define a `style for your type (derived window)` in resources like this -

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but i have searched over in google unable to find any link related to the following."Target types in style doesn't get applied on derived types." Can you please share any link?

Comment: Refer to the links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279773/wpf-window-style-not-being-applied and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml