# WPF Common Window Behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to define common behaviours between windows in a WPF application, for example:
All dialogs need to have certain properties set a certain way and respond to the escape key in order to close.

Is there any way to inherit from a shared base class? The xaml kicks up a fuss every time I attemp this by including the namespace in the xaml.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you just define one Window class and make everything else UserControls that you load into an instance of the Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is a common style for your Windows, see here for a discussion around the topic: [How to set default WPF Window Style in app.xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml)

If you still want to use a base window class, below works for me:

XAML:

```
<WpfApplication1:BaseWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Click me" />
    </StackPanel>

</WpfApplication1:BaseWindow>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class BaseWindow : Window
    {
        public BaseWindow()
        {
            Background = Brushes.Red;
            KeyDown += (sender, e) => { if (e.Key == Key.Escape) Close(); };
        }
    }

    public partial class Window1 
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The base class-method is described here: http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx, I tried it and it worked for me. You may define the base class that way or similar:

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
    public BaseWindow()
    {
        this.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Checking wether escape is pressed...
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can easily use that now:

```
<local:BaseWindow x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid></local:BaseWindow>
```

Of course you have to change the baseclass in the  codebehind too.