# Windows Style from ResourceDictionary don't apply

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

As I have multiple `Window`s in my application, I am looking for a solution that does not require me to set a `binding` on each `Window`.

I created a `ResourceDictionary` which has a `style` for the Window Background:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
</Style>
```

In my `XAML`, I set the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

There is no error, but my `Window` color stays white.

Comment: Please try Application.Resources instead of Window.Resources

Comment: Is your `ResourceDictionary` xaml file in the root folder of your project?

Comment: @LPL: it should still work in `Windows.Resources`.

Comment: @Dan Are you sure? AFAIK Resources affect only childs not themself, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to move it in the Application.Resources ( in App.xaml) : no changes !

Comment: @LPL: I've tested locally and it seems to work okay...

Comment: So why not on my application please ? In VS2012 i see the color in the form conceptor, but not when i run the application

Comment: @DanPuzey Are you sure it is working? Did you actually run your application? It doesn't work for me when I run it, but it shows up in the designer

Comment: For me too ! Ok in the designer....but not when i run the application !

Comment: I was running Kaxaml... Perhaps this needs more testing!

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni Take at look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml/460750#460750 The answer seems to suggest you can do this if you create your custom windows. Seriously it seems like more work to do. Well I'm a bit biased because my apps are all single window apps with multiple user controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new brush in your resource dictionary

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" Color="AliceBlue" />
```

and in your WPF window simply set the required resource to the window background property

```
<Window x:Class="GDD.Presentation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackground}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if i have multiples Window, i need to set the background for each, that's why i would like to use the style directly !

Comment: Downvoted For implicitly setting the StaticResource.

Comment: If the person who raised the question found the answer suitable and accepted it, I dont see a reason why it should be downvoted even if the StaticResource is being set implicitly! One should only down vote if the answer is completely irrelevant or wrong, not because someone did not use a best practice.

Answer (score 32):

This appears to be caused by a combination of the order in which WPF loads/processes styles from nested `ResourceDictionary`, and the specifics of the `Window` class.

Assume `MainWindow` is defined as per your post.  Now put the following in `Templates.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="myStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

If `MainWindow` has no style defined, then you will see that in the designer it appears with a red background.  The designer is parsing the whole Xaml and loading the resource dictionary, and then drawing the results.  The style is read before the window is drawn, and so the red background is applied.

When you run the application, the window is created before the `ResourceDictionary` is applied.  It looks for a default style (a style with `x:Key="{x:Type Window}"`) *before* the nested `ResourceDictionary` is processed, and finds nothing.  Therefore at runtime, the window appears with default colour.  (This is the behaviour described in the comments above.)  Remember that the style with `x:Key="{x:Type Window}"` has a default value that matches the Windows style.

This is borne out if you use `myStyle` explicitly.  If you add to your `Window` definition the attribute `Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"` you'll find that the designer fails, but you also get a run-time error, because `myStyle` hasn't been created at the time that the Window needs it.  If you switch to `Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}"` then you'll see that it works as you hope, because `DynamicResource` will update once the `ResourceDictionary` has been parsed and the style included.

So, applying this, you can fix the problem in one way by adding this to your Window element: `Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type Window}}"` - but this is cludgy.  The better solution is to include your resource dictionary in the `app.xaml` file, where it will be parsed before any window is opened and thus available to all:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The real issue here is that your `Window` is not really a `Window`: it is a class that derives from `Window` and will in fact be `MainWindow`, `Window2`, etc...  This means that the automatic style wireup for a `Window` will *never* work in this way, and some level of manual binding will unfortunately always be required.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I used in my application.  It lets me keep all my window styles together, and requires just a couple lines after the `<Window.Resources>` section.

Do your `Style` like so:

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle">
    <Setter Property="Window.Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
</Style>
```

Then, in your Window, after `</Window.Resources>` include the following:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MyWindowStyle}"/>
</Window.Style>
```