# Different presentation of WPF application - runtime vs designer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2012

Why do I get different presentations of my WPF application with the Visual Studio 2012 Designer versus the application at runtime?

See numbers 1 and 2 in my screenshot.

How can I avoid that behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the window style does not apply you can check out the solution here [Windows Style from ResourceDictionary don't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428417/windows-style-from-resourcedictionary-dont-apply)

And as for the inconsistency theres nothing you can do to avoid it. Since the designer is doing some static analysis and make the best guess of what will show up, but in reality the load order is never that easy to predict.