# How to move XAML codes from Window to Application.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

Following xaml code works good in the Window.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

I have five WPF Windows in the my WPF Application.

I dont want to put above code into every WPF Windows.

So, how to put above code into Application.Resources in order to work for 5 windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets develop a suitable `Style` from your triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="00:00:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This style can be placed in application resources.

Now the problem is, your window doesn't consume the default style from resource, so it needs to be explicitely applied (See [How to set default WPF Window Style in app.xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml) for more details)

```
<Window ... Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
```