# Style Defined in app.xaml is only applied in the Designer but not a Runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I put the two following Style in `App.xaml` of my WPF application. If I change the `FontSize` to a different value, the Designer of Visual Studio 2019 shows all the controls with the specified FontSize. If I run the app, the controls show a FontSize of 12.

```
<Application x:Class="testapp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testapp"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">


<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Themes/ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Themes/CheckBoxStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Themes/ComboBoxStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Themes/DataGridStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you research a bit, there has been an issue on this going back ten+ years on windows/pages. In design time **the designer** will get the style, but due to the `Page`/`Window` being derived types, during runtime they won't.

The fix (*or workaround depending one one's viewpoint*) is to name the style in app.xaml with `x:key` such as (*page only shown for brevity*):

```
<Style x:Key="pStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
</Style>
```

and then set to the static resource style on each page/window such as below

```
Style="{StaticResource pStyle}"
```

such as:

```
<Page x:Class="WPFStack.ListBox.ListViewQuestion"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFStack.ListBox"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Model"
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Style="{StaticResource pStyle}"
      Title="ListViewQuestion">
```

---

See [How to set default WPF Window Style in app.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw the old post, but was hoping for a fix/improvement in the meantime.

Comment: I was wondering that too, whether it was to old...but I tested the scenario under VS and Blend and that somewhat suggested it wasn't related to the editors. Interesting situation.