# How to set a style to all wpf windows based on a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have an application that has 2 versions and 2 databases. One is the real deal and the other is a test version so that the users can test stuff before they apply it on the real app.
I need to apply a style to all windows if the the user in the test mode so the users can differentiate when the have both versions open.
what I tried to do so far is that I created the style I want which is a simple border thickness and border brush setters and created a property in the Application file and
set it to true on start up if the version is the test version.
the code looks like this now.

**Application.xaml:**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTestVersion}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

**Application.xaml.vb:**

```
 Private _isTestVersion As Boolean = False
Public Property IsTestVersion() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isTestVersion
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isTestVersion = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup(e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnStartup(e)
    ' some irrelevant code 

    ' checking if the current version is the test version
    If My.Settings.b2ConnectionString.IndexOf("\dev;") > 0 Then
        IsTestVersion = True

    End If
End Sub
```

this obviously isn't working and i don't want to write code in every single window in the application. Is there a way solve this ?

**EDIT:**

applying the style is not the problem, the code below works as I want it to, what seems to be the problem is that the trigger isn't working

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Bad news for you - it's hard to apply style to all windows in application. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml

Comment: applying the style wasn't a problem 
                      ` <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        </Style>` 
this works perfectly fine the problem is that the triggers are not working