# Using ControlzEx.ThemeManager to change themes doesn't work for globally defined styles

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the [`ThemeManager` provided by the `ControlzEx` library](https://github.com/ControlzEx/ControlzEx/blob/develop/src/ControlzEx/Theming/ThemeManager.cs) to enable switching between themes in my application.

This works as expected when style properties are set directly on a control, for example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window Background="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush20}">
```

If I then call `ThemeManager.ChangeTheme()` the window background changes as expected.

However, if I try to use this same approach with a global style defined in a resource dictionary, like this:

**Controls.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush20}" />
    </Style>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Nothing happens when `ThemeManager.ChangeTheme()` is called.

My `App.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="ThemingDemoApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ThemingDemoApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Controls.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <local:ThemeProvider x:Key="{x:Static local:ThemeProvider.DefaultInstance}" />

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have tried adding a theme file to the App resources initially but this makes no difference.

Is it possible to use dynamic resources in globally defined styles, or do I have to implement dynamic styles on every control directly?

Here is a repo with a minimal example showing how it doesn't work: https://github.com/will-scc/ThemingDemoApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global window style in `Controls.xaml` isn't applied to the window in your example. This is not related to the theme manager you are using.

You should explicitly set the `Style` property of the window or use any of the other approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431940/how-to-set-default-wpf-window-style-in-app-xaml) to apply the `Style` to the `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="ThemingDemoApp.MainWindow"
        ...
        Style="{StaticResource windowStyle}" />
```

**Control.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="windowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush20}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Ah, I see your point. If I set a global style for `x:Type Button` the colour is correctly applied as I would expect. So is my understanding correct that `x:Type Window` doesn't work because my window is actually type `MainWindow` which, although it inherits `Window`, styles don't apply to inherited classes?

Comment: Something like that. See the link I provided for more information about the styling of windows.